# MailKit: ParseException when parsing an email string with email-address in displayname

Tags: c#, email, .net-6.0, mailkit, mimekit

I am currently working on a microservice that runs on DotNet6 and is using MailKit 3.1.0.
I have the following code snippet:

```
var from = "John Doe via noreply@company.com <noreply@company.com>";
var mailBoxAddress = MailboxAddress.Parse(from);
```

The second line of code leads to following Exception:
MimeKit.ParseException: Invalid addr-spec token at offset 0

I did some testing and found out that the following variations of the string work:

```
var fromAlternative1 = "John Doe via noreplycompany.com <noreply@company.com>";  // missing @
var fromAlternative2 = "JohnDoevianoreply@company.com<noreply@company.com>";  // no empty space
```

This leads me to the question wether it could exist a configuration that enables parsing the *from* string, there could be a bug or this behaviour is by design?

As a workaround im parsing the displayname and email-address by myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to properly quote the name if it contains `@` symbols or `.`.

Those are special characters that are required to be quoted by the email specifications.

In other words, the correct string would be:

```
"John Doe via noreply@company.com" <noreply@company.com>
```

Or, in C#:

```
var from = "\"John Doe via noreply@company.com\" <noreply@company.com>";
```